# Creating Tactics to practice in Arena chess

Tags: tactics

This is a two part question.
I have over 2000 tactics from books I would like to create in Arena chess (using Stock Fish), to practice.
How do I load and save these tactics in the Arena Chess GUI/Engine?

Is it possible to have these tactics randomly rotate as apposed to them cycling through in the order you entered them in?

Comment: I'm not sure Arena is the right tool for the job. By "using Stockfish" do you mean you want to play out the positions against Stockfish?

Comment: I guess it really can be something other than Arena, but like I mentioned, I have over 2000 tactics from books that I would like to load into Arena or whatever may be better and play them out. I did load 500 tactics into Lichess, but the issue is that Lechess only presents the tactics in the order you loaded them .I'm also looking for a GUI or Engine that will randomly cycle through the tactics as apposed loading them in the order you entered them.